# 3 packages have newer versions incompatible with dependency constraints

Tags: flutter, dart, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I think Dart has just updated a few of their packages, and it is becoming incompatible with my other packages. I am trying to get the Google Maps API started, but I can't seem to get past step 2 on the installation process. I am using this link: https://developers.google.com/maps/flutter-package/config, to get started.

I've researched, tried `pub upgrade`, `pub outdated`, `flutter pub upgrade --major-versions`, force upgrade, but it can't seem to budge. I even tried downgrading the versions and manually tried changing pubspec.yaml.

Here is my pubspec.yaml:

```yaml
name: google_maps_in_flutter
description: "A new Flutter project."
publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev

environment:
  sdk: '>=2.12.0 <3.0.0'

dependencies:
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  google_maps_flutter: ^2.5.3
  google_maps:
  js: ^0.6.3  
  flutter_map: ^6.1.0

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_lints: ^3.0.1
  
flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
```

but it gives me the following error when I run flutter pub upgrade:

```
google_maps 6.3.0 (7.0.0 available)
  js 0.6.7 (0.7.0 available)
  material_color_utilities 0.5.0 (0.8.0 available)
  No dependencies changed.
3 packages have newer versions incompatible with dependency constraints.
```

If anyone can please help with this problem, it would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Have you consider upgrading the Dart SDK version to >=3.0.0?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with you environment sdk.

You have in you `pubspec.yaml`:

```
environment:
  sdk: '>=2.12.0 <3.0.0'
```

If you check the three package mentionned by flutter pub update, you will see that they requeire higher than yours. For example, for `js` package:

```
environment:
  sdk: ">=3.1.0-66.0.dev <4.0.0"
```

for `material_color_utilities`:

```
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.17.0 <4.0.0"
```

for `google_maps`:

```
environment:
  sdk: '>=2.12.0 <4.0.0'
```

So to resolve this:

- Check all 3 package (go to their pub.dev page, click on theirs github reposotiry, and check the pubspec.yaml of the package.
- Choose the higher min version of the three package
- Update you pubspec.yaml

then run again `flutter pub update`.

I think setting environment to this will do the trick:

```
environment:
  sdk: '>=3.2.1 <4.0.0'
```